# automatically change number format in edittext android

Tags: android

i have issue when implement automatical change format number in editText. Ex: i set number in editText with "12.000", but when i add number in typing (i want to 120.000) ,  i get error or force close. this my code

```
EditText confirm_vol_before= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirm_vol_before);
//set value 
confirm_vol_before.setText("12.000");


 confirm_vol_before.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String val_confirm_vol_before = confirm_vol_before.getText().toString();                 
                 confirm_vol_before.setText(formatNumber(val_confirm_vol_before));
            }
        });


String formatNumber(String bd){
         bd=bd.replace(".", "");
          DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
          DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", symbols);
          bd=formatter.format(Long.parseLong(bd));
          return bd;
      }
```

and this logcat

```
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1013)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1855)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1809)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:759)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:955)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:974)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.Layout.getLineStartPos(Layout.java:500)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:837)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:809)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:793)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5097)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:129)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextInputFocus(FocusFinder.java:102)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:83)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:644)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:646)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6198)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5651)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1078)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1032)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3626)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3564)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3539)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$2.afterTextChanged(ViewFillOrder.java:425)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7369)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3713)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3564)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3539)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$2.afterTextChanged(ViewFillOrder.java:425)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7369)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3713)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3564)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3539)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$2.afterTextChanged(ViewFillOrder.java:425)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7369)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3713)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3564)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3539)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$2.afterTextChanged(ViewFillOrder.java:425)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7369)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3713)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3564)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3539)
10-20 12:52:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(12422):    at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$2.afterTextChanged(ViewFillOrd
```

so how to solve it ? thanks .. sorry for my english

Comment: Can you add your logcat info

Comment: plis cek my question again :D

Comment: need some clarification about question. What do you want to do and also point line where you are getting error.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String formatNumber(String bd){
  Double number = Double.valueOf(bd.replace(".", ""));
  DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
  return dec.format(number);   
}
```

Comment: my fuction that not error,.. please see my question again, i have updated, add logcat..